# expectOutputString heredoc fails on windows

Tags: phpunit

So I have a simple test which runs fine under linux but fails under windows:

```
    $output = <<<END
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Foo: Bar

Where am I?
END;

    $this->expectOutputString($output);

    // Works under linux but fails under windows
    echo $response;

    // Works under linux and windows
    echo str_replace("\r",'',$response);
```

It's a standard xampp php 5.5.15 phpunit 4.7.2 installation.  Tried it on two different windows machines.

Did some searching but could not come up with the magic keywords.  Refuse to accept that this has not been encountered before and can't really accept the notion that I need to hack my unit tests with a str_replace due to line endings on windows.

So where is the phpunit heredoc setting that will add \r under windows or conversely, remove them from echo under windows without messing up other things?

Comment: Try with `print_r(unpack('C*', $output));` on both platforms to see what line endings are being used. Also try to wrap echo with `ob_` and `unpack` to see what happens with line endings. Unfortunately I don't have Windows VM at hand so cannot test this at the moment. I don't think this is PHPUnit specific.

Comment: Thanks.  I know it's not phpunit specific.  I was just hoping that this was common enough that other phpunit testers had run into it and come up with something clever.